# Changing outgoing IP address randomly

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, iptables, routing, proxy

If we have a server with 10 IP Addresses, is there a clean way to randomly select one of them on each outgoing request as the source IP?

I tried Apache Mod Proxy, but apparently even if I change the source IP address by a script automatically, I have to reload Apache every time I do that.

Is there any tool or clean methods that can handle this?

---

## Edit: More Info

There are multiple customers hosted on a server,

Many of them are calling the same API (using cURL) which has a rate limit of 2 per second, so basically when one of customers sends 2 requests, the others can't get any!

I'm trying to rotate the servers "Outgoing IP Address (Source IP)" randomly on each request (the question here) or assign a dedicated "OUTGOING" IP to each host (which is not the question here).

Comment: Do you have control of your DNS?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I can change the DNS yes, but how does that affect the outgoing IP address? isn't it related to incoming requests?

Comment: Oh, if a client connects to you with TCP, the connection is on a specific IP address which cannot change until the TCP connection gets closed and reopened with a new IP... I thought maybe you were trying to get various clients on various IPs and not force a client on a certain IP after it connected (which is not possible unless you send them to a specific domain or sub-domain and that specific entry is attached to a specific IP.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke As you know, the outgoing IP address is usually the server's main IP address, so even if you have 10 hosts with 10 dedicated IP address (1 for each) all of them still use server's main IP address for outgoing requests. I'm trying to randomly rotate this outgoing IP address. incoming requests are not important at all, let's just assume we don't have any domains connected to this server.

Comment: Your best solution would be to get the API provider to relax the two connection per address limit.

Comment: @MosheKatz We have tried that, they said they don't have the option to make exceptions (implementing it would cost them) and we have to use different IPs.

Comment: I'm wondering if using cURL is possible, but after changing `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` we're not able to get the respond for some reason! it just gets timed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `statistic` iptables module with an `SNAT` rule like the following:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j SNAT --to-source IP2
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j SNAT --to-source IP3
Other rules for remaining IPs ...
```

You can choose either `random` mode or `nth` mode. 10 IPs give 0.1 probability for each single IP. No need to add a rule for the main interface IP (IP1) as it is used by default.

The rules above are applied to all traffic types. You can restrict it to specific protocol / port, etc as required.

Answer (score 2):

(Posted as a separate answer because it's to long to be a comment on Khaled's answer)

While using the `statistic` module works, the mathematics are off here. The first rule hits with `p=0.1` for any given packet. The second rule matches 10% of those remaining, so it hits with an overall `p=0.1*0.9=0.09`. The third rule applies with `p=0.1*0.9*0.9=0.081` and so on. For nine rules, there's only a total probability of `p=0.651`, so the implicit `DROP` would match one third of all packets. You can try for yourself:

```
$ for n in `seq 9`; do sudo iptables -A OUTPUT --dest 10.10.10.10 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j ACCEPT; done
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  --dest 10.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo ping -c 1000 -i 0.001 -W 0.002 10.10.10.10
$ sudo iptables-save -c | grep 10.10.10.10
[103:8652] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[90:7560] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[73:6132] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[74:6216] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[73:6132] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[70:5880] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[44:3696] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[43:3612] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[50:4200] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.10000000009 -j DROP
[380:31920] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -j DROP
```

You can see that the first rule matches about 10% of the packages, and the probability for a match drops down the line, while the final `DROP` gets lots more than it should. You can either adjust your probabilities, or easier, use not `probability` mode but `nth`:

```
$ sudo iptables -F OUTPUT
$ for n in `seq 10 -1 2`; do sudo iptables -A OUTPUT --dest 10.10.10.10 -m statistic --mode nth --every $n --packet 0 -j DROP; done
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  --dest 10.10.10.10 -j DROP
$ sudo ping -c 1000 -i 0.001 -W 0.002 10.10.10.10
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 10 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 9 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 8 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 7 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 6 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DROP
[100:8400] -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10/32 -j DROP
```